# Is it possible to overload an implicit or explicit cast operator of a class I don't own?

Tags: c#

Pretty much all in the title. Is it possible to create a cast overload on a class that I don't own. For instance, if I were to create a wrapper for the NotifyIcon class (which is sealed), I can't actually use it with anything; I'd have to return an instance which kinda kills the ability to do a decorator. Is it possible to create a cast overload somewhere where I can basically return the private instance of NotifyIcon? Sounds wonky, but I think it'll achieve what I want.

Normally, I'd do something like:

```
public static implicit operator MyClass(SomeOtherClass input)
{
    // do things to come up with a MyClass
}
```

But this only works when the return type is MyClass. I'd like to do something simple like:

```
public class MyPsuedoDecoratorClass
{
    private NotifyIcon _icon;

    public MyPsuedoDecoratorClass(NotifyIcon icon)
    {
        _icon = icon;
    }

    // some decorated methods

    public static implicit operator NotifyIcon(MyPsuedoDecoratorClass input)
    {
        return _icon;
    }   
}
```

So that I can use it as an initialization wrapper.

Comment: a From() TO() type pattern would be better for this. and unforntunatly you can't overload operaters in extension methods :(

Comment: No, I don't think the language allows you to achieve what you're looking for. Not sure where the downvotes are coming from. Maybe that is SO-speak for "No".

Comment: couldn't you just cast to object and then cast the object? I may misunderstand your question though

Comment: @RadioSpace in my current solution, I just have a public getter that returns the NotifyIcon object for use. I felt like a cast would be more elegant even if semantically ... misleading.

Comment: @CapTec, I don't think we're on the same page. This wrapper/decorator can't inherit from NotifyIcon because it is sealed. So casting to object and then to NotifyIcon wouldn't accomplish anything. I'm trying to come up with a solution on how to mimic a decorator on a sealed class.

Answer (score 0):

You basically can't, but you can use `NotifyIcon`'s tag to store it's artificial derived object which is still elegant:

```
public static class NotifyIconExtesionMethods {
    public static MyClass As<T>( this NotifyIcon notifyIcon ) {
        return notifyIcon.Tag as T;
    }
}

class MyClass {
    private NotifyIcon notifyIcon;

    public MyClass( ) {
        notifyIcon = ...;
        ...
        notifyIcon.Tag = this;
    }
    public T As<T>( ) {
        return notifyIcon as T;
    }
}

//In some method:
var notifyIcon = new MyClass( ).As<NotifyIcon>( );
...
var myClass = notifyIcon.As<MyClass>( );
```